# How to hide slug numbers with htaccess

Tags: permalinks, redirect

Is there a way to do an internal redirect from /product-category/brand-2 to /product-category/brand and still display brand-2 products and sub-categories?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to simply change the taxonomy slug from brand-2 to brand.

Assuming that can't be done for some reason ...

**Super important warning** Editing .htaccess is very dangerous and can completely mess up your website. Do not edit .htaccess if you do not know what you are doing. Always test .htaccess rules on a non-live server. Always back up your .htaccess file before editing it. Always be ready to immediately replace an edited .htaccess file with your backup. **You have been warned.** Do not blame me if this does not work or you blow out your website.

It's possible to use mod_rewrite; you would want to add this BEFORE the WordPress rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product-category/brand-2/(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/product-category/brand/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes, of course, that everything in the category slugged "brand" is also in the category slugged "brand-2."

Failing that, there are plugins that will allow you to redirect pretty much anything. Like this one:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Basically, that plugin hooks the template_redirect action, then uses wp_redirect to move the request to a new URL. You could build something similar in your own functions.php page.